# SQL query between four tables

Tags: python, mysql

I have question in relation to MySQL DB design and query data. 
[EER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B74Qd.png)

How to query to get houseno|idjobno ?
One houseno can have many job numbers.

Do I need to add extra column in jobno table and add foreign key between jobno and houseno?

Thank You for all your help.

Regards
Slaw

Comment: Can a job have many house numbers?

Comment: No, One job can have only one house.

Comment: So would it be logical to put the houseno in the job table?

Comment: It seems to me like your arealocation table is spurious> I would just put the address on the houseno table. I would remove the link between jobno and customername and make a link between jobno and houseno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT houseno from houseno h, arealocation a, customername c, jobno j
WHERE h.idAreaLocation=a.idAreaLocation AND 
a.CustomerID=c.CustomerID AND
c.CustomerID=j.j.CustomerID AND j.idJobNo = 1;
```